# Norm of rows or columns of non singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to prove that a non singular matrix has non zero norm columns or rows?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a column has zero norm then the column is the zero vector. The columns are not linearly independent and so the matrix is not invertible. Similar reasoning applies to rows.